# Using linear approximation for a two variable function to estimate $0.999^{10}(1 + \sin(0.01))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-approximation

I am trying to evaluate $$0.999^{10}(1 + \sin(0.01))$$ using linear approximation for a function with two variables, but I am a little confused as to how to do that, as I don't have any x or y terms.

If someone wouldnt mind explaining how I would go about this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks
Corey

Comment: you are looking for the linear approximation to $f(x,y)=x^{10}(1+ \sin(y))$ in the vicinity of $(1,0)$

Comment: Hey @WW1, Thanks heaps for that! It was a great help. I think I have it worked out now, but I would really appreciate it if you could confirm my working is correct.  $$f(x, y) = x^{10}(1+sin(y))
\\f_x(x, y) = 10x^9(1+sin(y))
\\f_y(x, y) = x^{10}cos(y) \\
\\f(x, y) \approx L(x, y) = f(1, 0) + f_x(1, 0)(x - 1)+f_y(1, 0)(y-0) = 1 + 10(x - 1) + (y-0) \\= 10x + y - 9
\\ \implies f(0.999, 0.01) \approx L(0.999, 0.01) = 10(0.999) + 0.01 - 9
\\ = 1.
$$Thanks again, Corey

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function:
$$
f(\varepsilon,\delta)=(1-\varepsilon)^{10}(1+\sin(\delta))
$$
Now expand around $(0,0)$ as far as the linear terms in $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ and put $\varepsilon=0.001$ and $\delta=0.01$.

Comment: More importantly, *control* the error terms.

Answer (score 0):

$$0.999^{10}(1 + \sin(0.01))
\approx (1-0.001)^{10}(1 + 0.01)
\\\approx (1-0.01)(1+0.01)
=1-0.0001
= 0.9999
$$

As a check,
the OS X calculator gives
0.99994516400519
from
$0.999^{10} 
=0.990044880209748
$
and
$\sin(0.01)
=0.009999833334167
$.

Comment: This omits some crucial subtleties which allow to omit the terms that are omitted in the expansions of $(1-\varepsilon)^{10}$ and of $\sin(\eta)$.

Comment: True. If you take more terms, you get more accurate answers.

Comment: Not the point: rather, one needs a guarantee that the terms you keep in the expansions of the power and of the sine indeed yield the precision in the end result that you say. By the way, note that the real result is *almost twice closer to 1* than what the expansions in your answer suggest, hence we know for a fact that something undetected is at work here (even if this something makes the error smaller rather than larger) and that the expansions in your answer are, in a way, not correct.

Comment: Probably the errors in the 2 terms somewhat cancel each other out.

Comment: I am sure you can figure out why they do.